# Is it possible to left join table in Yii2 so that the result is in the subarray?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Imagine a DB in which each **Product** has a relationship with the **Account** table.

If I make a request using `joinWith()` method

```
$products = Product::find()->joinWith('account')->asArray()->all();
```

I will get something like this:

```
[
    'title' => 'Product title',
    'price' => 'Product price',
    'accountId' => 1
    'account' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Account name',
        'location' => 'Account location'
    ]
]
```

It can be seen that the data from the account table was recorded in the subarray.

Is it possible to achieve the same result by using the function `leftJoin()`? That's how I tried to do it:

```
$products = Product::find()
    ->select('Product.*')
    ->leftJoin('Account', 'Account.id = Product.accountId')
    ->addSelect([
        'Account.name as accountName',
        'Account.location as accountLocation',
    ])
    ->all();
```

In this case result will be:

```
[
    'title' => 'Product title',
    'price' => 'Product price',
    'accountId' => 1,
    'accountName' => 'Account name',
    'accountLocation' => 'Account location'
]
```

Is it possible to `leftJoin()` table so that the result of joined table is in the subarray?

Comment: The `joinWith()` method already uses `LEFT JOIN` as join type. Why would you need to use `leftJoin()` instead of `joinWith()`? If you need to use other type of join you can specify it as 3rd param of `joinWith()` call. See [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ->with('account') to your query.

```
$products = Product::find()
->select('Product.*')
->leftJoin('Account', 'Account.id = Product.accountId')
->with('account')
->addSelect([
    'Account.name as accountName',
    'Account.location as accountLocation',
])
->all();
```

According to Yii2 Documentation it is the better approach to load the relation directly over joinWith() method, like you had it in your first example.
[Working with Relational Data](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)

[image]